# How to iterate n nested for loops each from 0 to n?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, permutation

for example if n = 2

```
// Nested loop for all possible pairs 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { 
            // here i have to use, i, j
        } 
    }
```

for example if n = 3

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) 
                 // here i have to use, i, j, k
```

But if n = k, then how to iterate n for loops each from 0 to n?

I tried a lot but am not able to come up with a solution.

Is there any way to do it? Please help.

Comment: You can use an array of counters `cntr[n]` and a carry-over loop, that is, you go through your list from element `[0]` upwards as long as incrementing an element produces a `0` (i.e. `cntr[i] == n-1` before incrementing which generates a carry-over to the next place). When you can increment one of your counters without producing a `0` you stop and emit your tuple of counters. I'll leave it to you to figure out when the up-counting stops.

Answer (score 0):

Can you test it with recursive function like this :

```
int foo(int n, int level)
{
  if(level == 0)
  {
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){

     //Do something

    }
    
    return someValue;
  }

  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    foo(n, --level);
  }

}


//Start it with level = n like this
foo(n,n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array for the indexes.

```
int indexes[n] = {0}; //initialize the whole array to zero
while {
    //use indexes[0..n-1] as you would i, j, k, ...
    
    indexes[n-1]++;
    //propagate carry
    for(i = n-1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (indexes[i] == n) {
            indexes[i-1]++;
            indexes[i] = 0;
        }
        else break; //early exit from propagation, in case it's not necessary
    }
    if ( indexes[0] == n) break; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the **recursive** solution *( with only a single loop and rest is the power of recursion )* , you just need to specify the `depth` and `n` where:

---

**depth** `which specifies the level of nested for loops you want to use`

---

**n** `size of each loop`

Below is the c++ implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;



void loop(int n, int depth, vector<int> &iteration){
    if(!depth){
        for(auto x:iteration)
            cout<<x<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
        return;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        iteration[iteration.size()-depth] = i;
        loop(n, depth-1, iteration);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    int depth = 3, n = 5;

    vector<int> iteration(depth);

    loop(n, depth, iteration);
    
    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
0 0 0 
0 0 1 
0 0 2 
0 0 3 
0 0 4 
0 1 0 
0 1 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 3 
0 1 4 
0 2 0 
0 2 1 
0 2 2 
0 2 3 
0 2 4 
0 3 0 
0 3 1 
0 3 2 
0 3 3 
0 3 4 
0 4 0 
0 4 1 
0 4 2 
0 4 3 
0 4 4 
1 0 0 
1 0 1 
1 0 2 
1 0 3 
1 0 4 
1 1 0 
1 1 1 
1 1 2 
1 1 3 
1 1 4 
1 2 0 
1 2 1 
1 2 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 4 
1 3 0 
1 3 1 
1 3 2 
1 3 3 
1 3 4 
1 4 0 
1 4 1 
1 4 2 
1 4 3 
1 4 4 
2 0 0 
2 0 1 
2 0 2 
2 0 3 
2 0 4 
2 1 0 
2 1 1 
2 1 2 
2 1 3 
2 1 4 
2 2 0 
2 2 1 
2 2 2 
2 2 3 
2 2 4 
2 3 0 
2 3 1 
2 3 2 
2 3 3 
2 3 4 
2 4 0 
2 4 1 
2 4 2 
2 4 3 
2 4 4 
3 0 0 
3 0 1 
3 0 2 
3 0 3 
3 0 4 
3 1 0 
3 1 1 
3 1 2 
3 1 3 
3 1 4 
3 2 0 
3 2 1 
3 2 2 
3 2 3 
3 2 4 
3 3 0 
3 3 1 
3 3 2 
3 3 3 
3 3 4 
3 4 0 
3 4 1 
3 4 2 
3 4 3 
3 4 4 
4 0 0 
4 0 1 
4 0 2 
4 0 3 
4 0 4 
4 1 0 
4 1 1 
4 1 2 
4 1 3 
4 1 4 
4 2 0 
4 2 1 
4 2 2 
4 2 3 
4 2 4 
4 3 0 
4 3 1 
4 3 2 
4 3 3 
4 3 4 
4 4 0 
4 4 1 
4 4 2 
4 4 3 
4 4 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Symbolically, you are generating all values of a base-`n` number of `n` digits. You perform this by starting from all zeroes and incrementing `n^n` times. Every time a digit reaches them, you reset it and carry to the next.

E.g. with `n=3`,

```
000 001 002 010 011 012 020 021 022 100 101 102 110 111 112 120 121 122 200 201 202 210 211 212 220 221 222
```

A possible implementation is with `n` counters.